# Binary / unary predicate functions cross-comparing ALL objects with ALL other objects in python

Tags: python, r, gis, geopandas, r-sf

I've asked [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55716263/overlaps-of-all-objects-within-the-same-dataset-in-arcpy-st-overlaps) before. Since the `arcpy` solution is a very cumbersome, I'm now looking for basically the same feature in `geopandas`. The question is: What is the fastest / best way to apply a binary predicate function ([e.g. `touches`](http://geopandas.org/reference.html#geopandas.GeoSeries.touches)) where *each* feature of `x` is compared to *every other* feature of either `x` or a different dataset `y`. I would expect an output similar to the default behaviour in R:

> If y is missing, `st_predicate(x, x)` is effectively called, and a square matrix is returned with diagonal elements `st_predicate(x[i], x[i])`.

To exemplify this with some dummy data and the function `st_overlaps()`:

```r
library(sf)

b0 = st_polygon(list(rbind(c(-1,-1), c(1,-1), c(1,1), c(-1,1), c(-1,-1))))
a0 = b0 * 0.8
a1 = a0 * 0.5 + c(2, 0.7)
a2 = a0 + 1
a3 = b0 * 0.5 + c(2, -0.5)
x = st_sfc(a0,a1,a2,a3)

plot(x)
```

[image]

```r
st_overlaps(x)
#> Sparse geometry binary predicate list of length 4, where the predicate was `overlaps'
#>  1: 3
#>  2: 3
#>  3: 1, 2
#>  4: (empty)
```

How can I achieve similar behaviour in `python` / `geopandas`? Apparently, `geopandas` automatically aligns `x` and `x`/`y` and an *element wise* comparison is performed (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52050498/geopandas-touches-method-on-geoseries-does-not-work-as-i-expect) and [this issue on github](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/750)). In python, running `x.overlaps(x)` just returns a pandas series with four `True` values.

```r
import geopandas as gpd

x.overlaps(x)
0      True
1      True
2      True
3      True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idiomatic Python way to express this is with list comprehension, e.g. to create list consisting of tuple (index: (overlapping-indices)), you would write

```
[ ( ind, 
    [ind2 for ind2, g2 in enumerate(series) if g.overlaps(g2)] 
  ) 
  for ind, g in enumerate(series) ]
```

Result:

```
[(0, [2]), (1, [2]), (2, [0, 1]), (3, [])]
```

But as noted by martinfleis this is not super efficient way to do it, as it does not use any kind of spatial indexing.

You might get better performance by using overlay operation, see http://geopandas.org/set_operations.html

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely not the fastest way, as is it just a simple iterator, but if your data are not huge it might do the work.

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

b0 = Polygon([(-1,-1), (1,-1), (1,1), (-1,1)])
a1 = Polygon([(1.5,0.2), (2.5,0.2), (2.5,1.2), (1.5,1.2)])
a2 = Polygon([(0,0), (2,0), (2,2), (0,2)])
a3 = Polygon([(1.5,-1), (2.5,-1), (2.5,-0.2), (1.5,-0.2)])

series = gpd.GeoSeries([b0, a1, a2, a3])

results = {}
for poly in series.iteritems():
    results[poly[0]] = []
    for poly2 in series.drop(poly[0]).iteritems():
        if poly[1].overlaps(poly2[1]):
            results[poly[0]].append(poly2[0])
```

It will give you dict with your values.

```
{0: [2], 1: [2], 2: [0, 1], 3: []}
```

However, be aware that it checks A->B and then B->A and that it also checks polygons even if they are clearly far away. To speed it up, you can use rtree spatial index to check only those who might overlap instead of checking every polygon with every other (twice).